# Javascript - Multiple inputs with unique ID and same class, javascript always pulls value from first input

Tags: javascript, loops, input, uniqueidentifier

I have a PHP loop pulling value from a database containing a customer review.  After each review, there is a "delete" button.

Here is the php loop

```
<button type="submit" name="delete" id="delete<?php echo $row4["id"];?>" value="<?php echo $row4["id"];?>" class="btn btn-primary delete" data-filter=".check1">Delete</button>
<div class="deleted<?php echo $row4["id"];?>" id="deleted<?php echo $row4["id"];?>"></div>
```

The script below takes the value from the "delete" button and uses ajax query to delete the record.   It then shows the message "deleted".

```
function delete_recommendation(){
    var action = "fetch_data";
    var id = $(".delete").val();
    $.ajax({
    url: "include/recommendation.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(){
    $('#deleted'+id).html('Removed!')
    $('#deleted'+id).addClass('text-danger')
    $('#delete'+id).addClass('d-none')
    }
});
}

$('.delete').click(function(){
    delete_recommendation();
});
```

The issues I am having is that if there are multiple reviews, and I click any of the delete buttons, it always deletes the first review listed.  I can't figure out how to make this unique.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the id of the row to delete from the id of the button clicked. According to the php it should be starting at character index 6, immediately after "delete":

```
function delete_recommendation( id){
    var action = "fetch_data";
    $.ajax({
    url: "include/recommendation.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(){
    $('#deleted'+id).html('Removed!')
    $('#deleted'+id).addClass('text-danger')
    $('#delete'+id).addClass('d-none')
    }
});
}

$('.delete').click(function(event){
   // id="delete<?php echo $row4["id"];?>
    delete_recommendation(event.target.id.substring(6));
});
```

The problem with the posted code is that

```
$(".delete").val();
```

[gets the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val).

Comment: can also take ID from data attribute :) Just a suggestion

Comment: Thank you so much!! That did exactly what i hoped.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are not looking for further answers feel free to accept this one :)